# How to get a specific field in a table layout in Views templates

Tags: views, theming

This is my first time using a table to display a Views template. How do you access a specific field so you can reorder them one by one yourself? I have 3 fields I want to place but I want one of the fields `field_house` to come out first, followed by `field_door` and `field_table`. I'm also asking so I can wrap each one in their own class making it easier to layout.

Comment: I got it!! The reason why I couldn't get it to work was because I kept writing my code in the wrong place. Just delete the loop `<?php foreach ($row as $field => $content): ?>` and replace it with actual code: `<?php print $row['field_house']; print $row['field_door']; print $row['field_table']; ?>` and it worked!

All this is of course still within the main loop `<?php foreach ($rows as $count => $row): ?>`.

Comment: @enhance you should post this as an answer so it's easy for others to see that you've solved it

Answer (score 1):

@Chaulky it should be pretty easy to make the changes suggested by @enhance.

- Take the views table template and copy it to your theme.
- Make the edits to your copy of the template as per @enhance's directions.
- Since you mentioned adding classes, you could either add the classes in the template or in the views interface.
- Save it as views-view-table-YOUR_VIEW_NAME.tpl.php.
- Clear caches, at least twice if once didn't do it.
- Continue theming and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to this thread, but incase someone comes across it, here is example code that works.

I removed the code I didn't need from the Views tpl, and added the fields within the foreach loop.

```
<table <?php if ($classes) { print 'class="'. $classes . '" '; } ?><?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $row_count => $row): ?>
      <tr <?php if ($row_classes[$row_count]) { print 'class="' . implode(' ', $row_classes[$row_count]) .'"';  } ?>>
        <td class="views-field views-field-title">
          <?php print $row['title']; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="views-field views-field-field-website-url">
          <?php print $row['field_website_url']; ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```